Live search Listing page coming wtih local url in production - Adobe commerce cloud
Live search Listing page coming wtih local url in production - Adobe commerce cloud.
Last time I've run the below command to update the base url and products.
but this time is not working any other things am I missing please help me on this.
bin/magento saas:resync --feed products && bin/magento saas:resync --feed productOverrides && bin/magento saas:resync --feed productattributes

Misspelled tag for "commerce cloud." Please remove or replace it with a correctly spelled one.
